# On webhook related load testing

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing

I was curious if anyone has done or looked into webhook load testing, where you’re testing the service that’s sending webhook events out to a server that’s receiving the webhook notifications, and testing that at scale. Note that in this scenario, the focus is the service emitting webhook events, and not so much on the receiver side (like how many webhook events it can sink/receive, hypothetically assuming it can take whatever you got), so the focus is how much you can POST/send out.

I’ve only found this article online that somewhat relates to the subject: https://www.testdevlab.com/blog/2017/11/how-to-load-test-webhook-services/

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are trying to solve and what have you done so far?

Comment: What I've done: set up a webhook client/receiver to receive the webhooks, that can be scaled for multiple instances, load balanced to a single URL.

Comment: Problem to solve: test webhook workflow infra at scale. Reverse of typical load test w/ many clients hitting a web server. Here we have many web servers (as needed) to receive the (client) webhook callbacks. Assuming many callbacks are made, we have to sink/receive that data somewhere via 1+ (web) server.